# how to query an object array and return only objects that match mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the collection below and would like to return all matches where firstParticipant.address or secondParticipant.address = 789 how to make this query with the mongoose and return only the objects that match the filter?

My document:

```
 {
        "_id": "25113",
        "title": "Jogo de futebol",
        "rounds": {
            "matches": [{
                    "firstParticipant": {
                        "address": "789",
                        "battlesWon": 0
                    },
                    "secondParticipant": {
                        "address": "748569874",
                        "battlesWon": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "firstParticipant": {
                        "address": "963",
                        "battlesWon": 0
                    },
                    "secondParticipant": {
                        "address": "741",
                        "battlesWon": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "firstParticipant": {
                        "address": "258",
                        "battlesWon": 0
                    },
                    "secondParticipant": {
                        "address": "789",
                        "battlesWon": 0
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

expected result:

```
 [{
        "firstParticipant": {
            "address": "789",
            "battlesWon": 0
        },
        "secondParticipant": {
            "address": "748569874",
            "battlesWon": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "firstParticipant": {
            "address": "258",
            "battlesWon": 0
        },
        "secondParticipant": {
            "address": "789",
            "battlesWon": 0
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) - Deconstruct array from documents
2. [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) - Filter documents by either `rounds.matches.firstParticipant.address` or `rounds.matches.secondParticipant.address` equal to 789.
3. [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) - Replaces the input document with `$rounds.matches`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$rounds.matches"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "rounds.matches.firstParticipant.address": {
            $eq: "789"
          }
        },
        {
          "rounds.matches.secondParticipant.address": {
            $eq: "789"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$rounds.matches"
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s7FPfOhCJh2)

> Output

```
[
  {
    "firstParticipant": {
      "address": "789",
      "battlesWon": 0
    },
    "secondParticipant": {
      "address": "748569874",
      "battlesWon": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "firstParticipant": {
      "address": "258",
      "battlesWon": 0
    },
    "secondParticipant": {
      "address": "789",
      "battlesWon": 0
    }
  }
]
```